# Fastest way to compute distances between consecutive vectors with numpy/scipy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, distance, insertion

I have a line growth algorithm where I need to:

- calculate the distances (euclidean) between consecutive vectors in an array
- insert a new vector where a distance is greater than a specific threshold

[image]

I usually do this in a very naive manner (see code below) and would like to know **how to compute distances between consecutive vectors the fastest way possible using numpy** (and scipy if needed).

```
import math


threshold = 10
vectorList = [(0, 10), (4, 8), (14, 14), (16, 19), (35, 16)]

for i in xrange(len(vectorList)):
    p1 = vectorList[i]
    p2 = vectorList[i+1]
    d = math.sqrt((p2[0] - p1[0])**2 + (p2[1] - p1[1])**2)
    if d >= threshold:
        pmid = ((p1[0] + p2[0]) * .5, (p1[1] + p2[1]) * .5)
        vectorList.insert(i+1, pmid)
```

EDIT: 
I've come up with the following workaround but I'm still concerned with the distance computation.

I would need to compute the distances between a vector and its next neighbor in a list instead of calculating a whole distance matrix (all vectors against each others) as I'm doing here.

```
import numpy as np

vectorList = [(0, 10), (4, 8), (14, 14), (16, 19), (35, 16)]
arr = np.asarray(vectorList).astype(float)


dis = distance.cdist(arr, arr).diagonal(1)
idx = np.where(dis > 10)[0]
vec = (arr[idx] + arr[idx+1]) * .5
arr = np.insert(arr, idx+1, vec, 0)

# output
array([[ 0. , 10. ],[ 4. ,  8. ],[ 9. , 11. ],[14. , 14. ],[16. , 19. ],[25.5, 17.5],[35. , 16. ]])
```

Comment: Does this code reliably handle the growth of `vectorList`?

Comment: For given `vectorList` converted to a 2d array, it should be easy to get `d` with quick numpy calculations  (`np.diff` might give you a starting point).  But incrementally adding elements will be harder.

Comment: In the loop after an insert, what is `i` supposed to be, or rather what should `p1` be?  The `pmid` value?  The `p2` of the previous iteration?  You might need to add another tuple to test this.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the pointers and apologies for the late reply. `np.diff` seems to compute differences between vectors, not distances. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Question has been updated.

Comment: I meant `diff` as the starting point. You distance calc uses differences.

Comment: Could you provide a simple example ? I'm confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [209]: vectorList = [(0, 10), (4, 8), (14, 14), (16, 19), (35, 16), (39,50)] 
In [210]: vectorList                                                            
Out[210]: [(0, 10), (4, 8), (14, 14), (16, 19), (35, 16), (39, 50)]
```

I added a point, making 3 possible insertion points.

```
In [212]: np.diff(vectorList, axis=0)                                           
Out[212]: 
array([[ 4, -2],
       [10,  6],
       [ 2,  5],
       [19, -3],
       [ 4, 34]])
In [213]: np.sum(np.diff(vectorList, axis=0)**2,1)                              
Out[213]: array([  20,  136,   29,  370, 1172])
```

distances:

```
In [214]: np.sqrt(np.sum(np.diff(vectorList, axis=0)**2,1))                     
Out[214]: array([ 4.47213595, 11.66190379,  5.38516481, 19.23538406, 34.23448554])
```

Mean values:

```
In [216]: arr = np.array(vectorList)                                            
In [217]: arr                                                                   
Out[217]: 
array([[ 0, 10],
       [ 4,  8],
       [14, 14],
       [16, 19],
       [35, 16],
       [39, 50]])

In [218]: (arr[:-1]+arr[1:])/2                                                  
Out[218]: 
array([[ 2. ,  9. ],
       [ 9. , 11. ],
       [15. , 16.5],
       [25.5, 17.5],
       [37. , 33. ]])
```

I could do something similar without `diff`:

```
d = np.sqrt(np.sum((arr[1:]-arr[:-1])**2,1))
```

The jumps that exceed the threshhold:

```
In [224]: idx = np.nonzero(d>10)                                                
In [225]: idx                                                                   
Out[225]: (array([1, 3, 4]),)
In [227]: _218[idx]       # the mean values to insert                                                            
Out[227]: 
array([[ 9. , 11. ],
       [25.5, 17.5],
       [37. , 33. ]])
```

Use `np.insert` to insert all values.

```
In [232]: np.insert(arr.astype(float), idx[0]+1, _227, axis=0)                  
Out[232]: 
array([[ 0. , 10. ],
       [ 4. ,  8. ],
       [ 9. , 11. ],
       [14. , 14. ],
       [16. , 19. ],
       [25.5, 17.5],
       [35. , 16. ],
       [37. , 33. ],
       [39. , 50. ]])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using sklearn [NearestNeighbors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#finding-the-nearest-neighbors)

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import numpy as np

def distance(p1,p2):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(np.diff([p1,p2], axis=0)**2,1))

def find_shortest_distance(vectorList):
    nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2, metric=distance).fit(vectorList)
    distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(vectorList)

    result = distances[:, 1]
    return result

vectorList = [(0, 10), (4, 8), (14, 14), (16, 19), (35, 16)]
```

which returns:

```
result
Out[57]: array([ 4.47213595,  4.47213595,  5.38516481,  5.38516481, 19.23538406])
```

This might be overkill for your problem, but this solution doesn't require the points to be in consecutive order.

Timings (slower than numpy):

```
%timeit find_shortest_distance(vectorList)
478 µs ± 2.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: This is indeed overkill but I appreciate the suggestion + I learned something. Also thank you for providing a timing.